# How can I securely send a request from client to server

Tags: javascript, authentication, flask

I am using Flask for my backends so if I want to send a request from client (js) to my backend (flask) I will normally use `fetch()` in js to send a request and I receive in my backend, but the problem is that using Chrome developer tools everyone can see to where I am sending a request and like I am getting tons of unwanted request to my backend which are not sent by my client (js) so people are sending. Any way to prevent it?

I have also tried **API** auth but the problem is they are seeing my API keys and sending request. Please help me.

Comment: Depending on your case, maybe you can restrict how many times a client is allowed to use an `API key`.

Comment: @YazanWYusuf can you tell me how to do that

Answer (score 2):

The browser belongs to the user. It is completely under their control.

It is impossible to send data from the browser without the user being able to inspect it.

You can't secure the browser from the user who owns it.

There is no way to restrict an API so that it can only be accessed by your code running in the user's browser.

Answer (score -1):

While every thing on the client belongs to the client , HTTP response headers can be leveraged to tighten up the security of web apps, typically just by adding a few lines of code. Depending on the technology your using

Comment: "HTTP response headers can be leveraged to tighten up the security of web apps " — No response header will prevent the user from inspecting the request.

Comment: "typically just by adding a few lines of code" — This might be a good answer if you very less vague about what those lines of code were (assuming that you were correct, which I don't think you are).

Comment: "Depending on the technology your using" — It's going to be HTTP / HTML / JavaScript.